# Blank cells/rows aren't showing up

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to find all the blank cells in a spreadsheet I have. I'm using `.getDataRange()` to get all the cells with data. The problem is, I can't get the empty cells / rows to show up.

For example:

row 1 | test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6
row 2 |
row 3 |
row 4 |

If I use `.getDataRange` here, and do `.getNumColumns` and `.getNumRows`, It will return columns = 6, and rows = 1. This is the problem I'm having because I need it to return all the rows...but since the other rows don't have any data in them, it's like they don't exist.

My code is:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

  var rowCheck = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows(); //gets all rows
  var data =  spreadsheet.getDataRange(); //gets range of all data in spreadsheet

  //set blank cells to '0'
  var columns = data.getNumColumns();
  var rows = data.getNumRows();
  Logger.log("columns: " + columns + ",,, rows: " + rows);
```

So I guess the question is: How do I get all the rows to show up regardless of if it contains data or not?

Comment: The command getDatRange returns the smallest rectangular area from the top of a sheet to the furthest cells that contain data.  So yes rows below cells that contain data won't be included in the dataRange because they don't contain data.  What do mean when you say that you want them to show up?

Comment: @Cooper I meant that I would like to iterate through all the rows regardless if they have data or not. But seeing as .getDataRange didn't bring up any empty rows, I was only iterating through the cells that had values in them. I think I can do it with .getMaxRows and Columns though.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the range? Set empty to 0? Of the whole sheet or only your data-containing rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

## Getting the Values

My understanding is that getDataRange() gets the range of all data on the sheet. 
So when you say in your code the following:

```
var data =  spreadsheet.getDataRange(); //gets range of all data in spreadsheet
```

Let me be sure that you understand that this command does not return any values it only returns a range.  If you want the values then you can do this.

```
var dataA = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

In this case you will get values in a 2 dimensional array.